# OAuth Exception #2500

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to access my Facebook account with an App access code (because I want indefinate access - I do not want an access code which can expire)

I have tried the following code using AppId and AppSecret (which are valid) :

```
string accesstoken = m_AppId & "|" & m_AppSecret;
Facebook.FacebookClient fb = new Facebook.FacebookClient(accesstoken); 
Facebook.JsonObject fbMe = (Facebook.JsonObject)fb.Get("me");
```

and the last line throws an exception stating

OAuth Exception #2500 An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using an App Access Token, the path `me` cannot be determined by the Graph API, because the App Access Token is not connected to a specific User.

Solution is either specify a (app-scoped if using Graph API v2.0) `user_id` instead of `me`, or use a User Access Token.

Comment: Thank you for your response. 1) My facebook logon/account has three fields forename,surname,email address. How do I use these to obtain a user_id?  2) Do User Access Tokens expire, if they do, I don't think they are suitable. I need to have indefinite access.

Comment: You should definitely use User Access Tokens, because otherwise you'll not be able to retrieve more than the `basic_profile`. The stuff you tried will not work. Regarding expiration, you're not the first developer which has to deal with that. Read the docs.

Comment: I don't think you understood. If you want to access for example the Email address, you have no choice but to use a User Access Token.

Comment: I want to access posts on my facebook pages from server code.  I dont mind what type of access token I use as long as it will last indefinitely (subject to password not being changed of course).  Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23907802/post-to-a-facebook-page-without-manage-pages-permission-using-php/23908207#23908207 and be sure to add the read_stream permission as well

Comment: Thank you for posting this I appreciate it. It does not help unfortunately. The initial access token was 1 hour and the extended one was 2 months.  As I said - I need an indefinite access time access token.  Is this possible ?

Comment: Have you read my answer about Page Access Tokens? These are indefinite. Have you tried this?

Comment: Yes thanks. I did try it. I followed it through, extended the access token and then pasted it into the graph API debug page and that said the token expires in "about 2 months".

Comment: I tried this with one of my v1.0 apps, and this works. tried it with one of my v2.0, and indeed there's a 2 month validity. Do you happen to have a v1.0 app?

Comment: no it is a v2.0 App.  I understood that all new Apps have to be V2.0 ?

Comment: All new apps since April 30th 2014 are V2.0. Afaik the validity change is not documented.