# Post to a facebook page without "manage_pages" permission using php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have a website that contains blog post. we need to post blogs automatically to facebook page. Curently I could post to my timeline. But I could'nt post to facebook page. I've search in google. many code says we need manage_pages permission. * My App,Facebook page in same account. I have submitted manage_pages for approval. They said you could post to your page without manage_page permissions due to you are the administrator of app and facebook pages. But always I'm receiving #200 error. Their detialed reply is "You do not need to request these permissions because your blog or CMS is integrated with an app that you admin. As an App admin, you can already access these permissions and post to your Timeline or a page you admin. You can provide access to additional users by adding them as developers of your App." I need code for post to facebook page without manage_pages permissions as they explained

Answer (score 6):

Request a new User Access Token by using the Graph API Explorer (with `manage_pages` permission, eventually in conjunction with `publish_pages`). Be sure to use one of your own apps, because you want to exchange the generated (short-lived) access token to a long-lived one:

Copy the newly generated User Access Token from the according form field from the Graph Explorer, open a new browser tab and paste a URL like the following

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id={your_app_id}&client_secret={your_app_secret}&fb_exchange_token={user_token_from_last_step}
```

This will create a long-lived User Access Token. Now, copy this new Access Token from the browser tab's content to the Graph Explorer (into the according form field for Access Tokens).

Now, you can call `/me/accounts` with this Access Token, and you'll receive a list of the pages you administer. Choose a Page Access Token from the list, and verify the generated token via

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken?q={generated_page_token}
```