# Difference in permissions between using Graph API Explorer and testing out on local environmennt

Tags: angularjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using the JavaScript SDK for Facebook on my Angular webapp. I have the webapp registered on Facebook Dashboard (I'm listed as Developer). The objective is to make a post on a Facebook Page AS THE PAGE and say "Hey, I posted here on this page through my webapp". I am the administrator of this Page.

Now, since I'm a Developer of the webapp and Administrator of Page, I saw in the documentation that I don't need to submit the webapp for review to get permissions like manage_pages and publish_pages. So I followed the instructions found here on SO to use the Graph API explorer to test things out: [Post to a facebook page without "manage_pages" permission using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23907802/post-to-a-facebook-page-without-manage-pages-permission-using-php)

Using the Graph API Explorer, I can select extended permissions like "manage_pages" and "publish_pages", get the right access tokens, and then find the right page_access_token and post to that Page all through the Explorer. But it seems that I can't do this out on my local environment (directly through the webapp) due to #200 authentication error.

I am confused because it's easier to get the Graph API Explorer to do what I want (in this case, posting on a Page through my webapp). When I'm not using the Graph API explorer, do I absolutely need to submit to Facebook for review to get permissions like "manage_pages" and "publish_pages"?

(For extra information, I'm logging into my webapp using a Facebook login that I implemented using JavaScript SDK. when I call "me/permissions", I get public_profile and email back as responses)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that if you are a Developer of the app (under Facebook Dashboard), then you can indeed go ahead and use manage_pages and publish_pages without submitting app for review. When you try to login using Facebook, you will see the permissions dialog (Log in with Facebook) and some warnings about how you are using extended permissions. After you click yes to that, THEN you will see an additional dialog that asks you "XYZ would like to post to pages for you" ... so there were 2 dialogs involved, not just the initial default one.

However, this can be pretty confusing, because let's say you are not registered as a developer/admin to that app under FB dashboard. If you've already granted basic permissions to your app in the past, then you will never see the extended permissions dialog pop up (instead seeing something pop up very quickly and disappear), which will be very confusing and won't let you use those extended permissions.