# single user Facebook app need long life access token for Fan page same user, not working since April 29th 2015

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I have A Facebook app that I am administrator for, I followed these steps in these two videos:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G1999fCMcMw

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5TQqW3-Stg4

to get a long life access token for my Fan page, community fan page created with same email as the app. the app does not have a platform, it is used by me the single user, to send updates to my own Fan page, so no log in page or website to access to authorise, so had to use Graph API and the tools page that Facebook provide to get the access token and hard code this into my C# console middleware program that sends weather updates to this fan page.
The app appeared to be fine, after the first attempt, pre April 29th update, but the app was version 2.2 already.
I was successful in getting a long life token based on the videos, well altered the steps in the last one by using the 2 month access token instead of the hour one to get never expire one, this worked up until the changes that were made by facebook on 29th April 2015, now the same steps will produce a never ending token and says success on the post in Graph APi facebook page, but when i used it in the program it says OAuth Exception #283 requires extended permission - mange_pages. i have ticked this and allowed this and when i checked me/permissions it says the token has this access. I have made sure i am on my own app when getting token and not Graph API, and i also have Client OAuth Login selected as yes. I also updated the version of SDK .Net Facebook api dll from Nuget and it has not changed the issue.
 this is my code
`FacebookClient client;
     string access_token = "CAA..."
     client = new FacebookClient(access_token);
     client.Version = "v2.2"; //newly added to see if made any difference but didn't
     client.Post("/me/feed", new { message = "Message" });`

I will not be able to apply to facebook for this permission as I don't have a platform for them to test in, it was previously rejected for this reason. believe and correct me if this has change due to the recent changes, but if you the developer are the only user and can authorise access yourself you didn't need to have public facebook approval for it to work?

Comment: I don't really understand, are you using/wanting a long-lived User Access Token, or an eternal Page Access Token? If you just want to post to a Page, the latter should be the right one...

Comment: I want to be able to post to a page, so think i need the page token yes, but tried both videos, just trying everything. Any advice on why it not working?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a eternal Page Access Token, have a look at the answer here:

- [Post to a facebook page without "manage_pages" permission using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23907802/post-to-a-facebook-page-without-manage-pages-permission-using-php/23908207#23908207)

Comment: those are the same steps really, i do get a never expire token already, but when i use it in my application it gives the error that i need extended permission - manage_pages, even though after checking the token and it saying it has manage_pages. Is there any thing i need to do on the app side or in my program to change the code?

Comment: So, you set the generated eternal Page Access Token in `string access_token = "..."`?

Comment: correct yes, and double checked fan page and set the app to public and it says it has the manage page option

Comment: Then open a bug with Facebook