# Best way to achieve automatic posting to facebook using nodejs

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-feed

I'm developing a nodejs app which basically posts in an automatic way, videos to a Facebook page. I'm the admin of the page so user auth should be done once. Up until now, I was using an unpublished facebook app to test it, but I just realize that while the app is not released, no one except myself can see the videos posted (they should be public...).

It is important to note that to get the user token I manually went to de graph api explorer, requested it, and pasted the token on the script. The thing is that validating my app is an  almost impossible task giving facebook security concerns; there is no way for them to "understand" that I, the owner of the app and admin of the page, is the only user who can access the app and its capabilities.

I've tried getting a token with the Graph API explorer as "app", manually, and others can see the videos posted using this method (which shows posted as "Open Graph API", on the feed); but the problem is that I can't find a way to keep renovating automatically (script side) this type of token (which can't be extended, and last only a couple of hours). This is a crucial part, given that the app will be running on a server that has to handle everything automatically.

So, maybe there is a way to renovate my "Open Graph API" token on expiration on the script itself, or maybe there is a workaround to publish the app on facebook in a quick and achievable way (given my evident lack of time...)

Anyway, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don't really understand why you don't make your app public (there's a difference between making the app public, that's an app setting, and following/submitting to Login Review!). It's also not clear to me why you're not using an eternal Page Access Token to post to your Page (as the Page itself).

Have a look at my answer at

- [Post to a facebook page without "manage_pages" permission using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23907802/post-to-a-facebook-page-without-manage-pages-permission-using-php/23908207#23908207)

to see how you can create such a Page Access Token.

Furthermore, as admin/tester/developer user of an app, you can also grant this app extended permissions without having to go through Login Review!

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/what-is-login-review

Comment: Ohhh meeennn. Can't believe how I missed that big button to make it public next to my app name.  That did the trick